# How to suppress the "checking compatibility of add-ons" dialog in Firefox with Selenium?

Tags: firefox, selenium, firefox-addon

Since updated to Firefox 12, every time I launch Firefox with a particular profile with Selenium (in python and Mac OS 10.7) it pops up the "checking compatibility of add-ons" dialog, and sometimes this dialog would stay up forever and I have to force-quit it. After forcing quit it, a new instance of the Firefox would continue to launch and finishes the rest of the Selenium script successfully though.

I have tried setting `extensions.checkCompatibility` to `false`. This fixed it if I launched Firefox normally, but not if I launch it with Selenium. Any idea on how to suppress this dialog? Thanks!

Comment: Probably, download the latest version of firefox as firefox 13 is in town :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This dialog is shown only once whenever Firefox is updated. The reason it is shown each time for you is probably that Selenium creates a new profile each time. If you set `extensions.lastAppVersion` preference to `"12.0"` (or whatever the current Firefox version is) then Firefox will no longer think that it has been updated and won't show this dialog. However, it should be easier to add a `extensions.showMismatchUI` preference and set it to `false`, this will suppress this dialog (but not the other upgrade actions).

*Side-note*: `extensions.checkCompatibility` preference no longer does anything starting with Firefox 3.6, it is a version-specific preference in the current Firefox versions. So you would have to set `extensions.checkCompatibility.12.0` preference instead. That disables compatibility checking for extensions completely however, not just the dialog you are concerned about.

Answer (score 1):

> I have tried setting extensions.checkCompatibility to false. This fixed it if I launched Firefox normally, but not if I launch it with Selenium.

The reason it won't when you launch it with Selenium is the Firefox Driver will create a temporary profile in the temporary files directory, slowing down tests and taking up unnecessary space.

Create a profile for your test purposes and set what you need. Full instructions to create the SeleniumProfile can be found at https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles

In Java I have the following:

```
protected WebDriver createFirefoxDriver() {     
    File proFile = new File("C:\\Users\\<username>\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\xxxxxx42.SeleniumProfile");
    FirefoxProfile ffProfile = new FirefoxProfile(proFile);
    WebDriver ffDriver = new FirefoxDriver(ffProfile);

    return ffDriver;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this to remove the **"checking for addon's compatibility"** Dialog. This is based on the Windows operating system..

Create a temporary FF Profile and start the server with that profileas shown below.

```
java -jar selenium-server-x.x.x.jar -firefoxProfileTemplate "/path/to/the/temp/profile"
```

Now use the following code.

```
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;
public class Test {

public static void main(String ar[]) {

Selenium sel = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://www.google.com/");

sel.start();
}
}
```

Now in the Run command type "%TEMP%" and you can see there a folder with same name as the selenium session. Copy the folder contents and replace them with your temp profile Contents.

Follow the steps below to remove the Addons compatibility.

1 . Create a new FF Profile
2 . Set the FF Profile as per required settings
3 . Just run a sample program of selenium such that it invokes firefox.
4 . Now you can find a folder with the same name as Selenium Session created somewhere in your sytsem. ( Most probably in the directory where the Temporary Content is saved)

5 . Copy the folder contents and replace them with the newly created profile.

Now you can use the newly created profile whenever required. Whenever FF is updated , always check whether the existing addons are compatible with the Existing version by once invoking firefox with the Profile.